# Java For Loop in an Array

Tags: java, for-loop, scheduling, disk

This question is probably best suited towards anyone with some insight into disk read scheduling.

I have the code:

```
for(int i = readqueue_tail; i<readqueue_head; i++)
```

I then use i to access elements in a readqueue array, which goes up to 255. However, once the queue is filled, it starts filling again from 0 (as these requests will have been serviced it doesn't matter).

The issue I'm having is searching from the tail up to the readqueue_head as when the head loops round and goes past 0 again the loop condition fails. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other options is just use modulo.

```
int i = readqueue_tail;
while (i != readqueue_head)
{
    i = (i + 1) % 256;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = readqueue_tail;
boolean stop = false;
while(!stop) {
  // process the queue item

  // advance the position
  if(i<readqueue_head) {
    i++) 
  } else {
    i = readqueue_tail;
  }
}
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I started using this but switched to the modulo (less code ^^).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = readqueue_tail; i<readqueue_head; i++) {
if(readqueue_tail == readqueue_head )
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = readqueue_tail; i<readqueue_head; i++) {
 if (i == readqueue_head) {
  i = readqueue_tail;
 }
}
```

just to be clear, this is an infinite loop.